# algorithms - exponentiation -

Tags: python, algorithm

I have tried hard, but cannot think of a way to do a^(b^c) mod p for some reason. I am able to see the thread for a^b^c etc .. mod p, and even though this is only a slight change, I am not able to do it

This is what I have in Python code:

def exponent_mod(a, b, c, m):

```
def modular_pow(base, exponent, modulus):
    result = 1
    while (exponent > 0):
        if (exponent % 2 == 1):
           result = (result * base) % modulus
        exponent = exponent >> 1
        base = (base * base) % modulus
    return result

m_ = modular_pow(a, b, m)
return modular_pow(m_, c, m)
```

Comment: Could you share what you've done so we could see where you're going wrong?  If you're using the caret `^` - you're getting an `XOR` value instead.  The operator for exponentiation in Python is the double asterisk `**`.

Comment: You're trying to reinvent the wheel, please refer to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

Comment: The only obstacle I see here is that you could get into some trouble if your exponents get larger. Therefore I would search for a analytical simplification of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a valid reason to have an extra method (nor do I understand the intention or purpose of the bit shifts).  If you're trying to get a<sup>b<sup>c</sup></sup> mod p, then let's just do it directly.

```
def modular_pow(a, b, c, p):
    return (a**(b**c)) % p
```

A more efficient way, as suggested, would be using [Python's built-in `pow()` method:](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow)

```
def modular_pow(a, b, c, p):
    return pow(a, b**c, p)
```

Comment: Better to do `pow(a,b**c,p)`